# More problems importing Flask extensions: Flask-WTForms & Flask-Login

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, flask-wtforms

Running Ubuntu Trusty 64-bit mode... Writing Flask app/framework using MongoDB, Flask-WTForms, & Flask-Login. Developing under virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper. Here is the setup:

[installed pkgs as listed by PIP:]

```
(default_venv)rip@MSI2:/arch/web-projects/oscargrantcommittee/default$ pip list

argparse (1.2.1)
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-Login (0.2.11)
Flask-WTF (0.12)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
pip (1.5.4)
pymongo (3.0.3)
setuptools (2.2)
Werkzeug (0.10.4)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
WTForms (2.0.2)
```

[listing of directory containing pkgs for venv:]

```
===========================================================================
rip@MSI2:~/.virtualenvs/default_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ l
bson/                               _markerlib/
easy_install.py                     markupsafe/
easy_install.pyc                    MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7.egg-info/
flask/                              pip/
Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg-info/        pip-1.5.4.dist-info/
Flask_Login-0.2.11-py2.7.egg-info/  pkg_resources.py
flask_login.py                      pkg_resources.pyc
flask_login.pyc                     pymongo/
flask_wtf/                          pymongo-3.0.3-py2.7.egg-info/
Flask_WTF-0.12.dist-info/           setuptools/
gridfs/                             setuptools-2.2.dist-info/
itsdangerous-0.24-py2.7.egg-info/   werkzeug/
itsdangerous.py                     Werkzeug-0.10.4.dist-info/
itsdangerous.pyc                    wtforms/
jinja2/                             WTForms-2.0.2.dist-info/
Jinja2-2.8.dist-info/
(we can see that the files are actually there! I even checked the __init__ script in the Flask-WTF pkg)

============================================================
```

[The offending code:]

```
    import os
    from flask import request, url_for, render_template, redirect, flash, \
                  get_flashed_messages, session
    from app import app
    import pymongo
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from werkzeug import secure_filename
    from flask_wtf import Form
    (note: 'from flask.ext.wtf...' doesn't work either, but crashes in a
    different place; see below)

    from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField, FileField, HiddenField, \
                    SubmitField, PasswordField, BooleanField
    from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, EqualTo, Length, Regexp
    from forms import AddActionForm, UpdateActionForm
    from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required,\
                            login_user, logout_user, current_user

=====================================================
```

[the error msg when trying to import from flask_wtf:]

```
(default_venv)rip@MSI2:/arch/web-projects/oscargrantcommittee/default$ ./run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/arch/web-projects/oscargrantcommittee/default/app/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/arch/web-projects/oscargrantcommittee/default/app/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import Form
ImportError: No module named flask_wtf

=============================================================
```

[the error msg when trying to import from flask.ext.wtf:]

```
(default_venv)rip@MSI2:/arch/web-projects/oscargrantcommittee/default$ ./run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/arch/web-projects/oscargrantcommittee/default/app/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/arch/web-projects/oscargrantcommittee/default/app/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flask.ext.wtf import Form
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf
(bote that in this case the exception comes from exthook.py)

==============================================
```

[part of exthook.py:]

```
        modname = fullname.split('.', self.prefix_cutoff)[self.prefix_cutoff]
        for path in self.module_choices:
            realname = path % modname
            try:
                __import__(realname)
            except ImportError:
                exc_type, exc_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
                # since we only establish the entry in sys.modules at the
                # very this seems to be redundant, but if recursive imports
                # happen we will call into the move import a second time.
                # On the second invocation we still don't have an entry for
                # fullname in sys.modules, but we will end up with the same
                # fake module name and that import will succeed since this
                # one already has a temporary entry in the modules dict.
                # Since this one "succeeded" temporarily that second
                # invocation now will have created a fullname entry in
                # sys.modules which we have to kill.
                sys.modules.pop(fullname, None)

                # If it's an important traceback we reraise it, otherwise
                # we swallow it and try the next choice.  The skipped frame
                # is the one from __import__ above which we don't care about
                if self.is_important_traceback(realname, tb):
                    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb.tb_next)
                continue
            module = sys.modules[fullname] = sys.modules[realname]
            if '.' not in modname:
                setattr(sys.modules[self.wrapper_module], modname, module)
            return module
     87 --> raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname) <-- line 87
    (the last line is where the exception comes from when trying to 
    import     from flask.ext.wtf)

================================================================
```

-- A few other notes: commenting out everything to do w/ Flask-WTF gives the same errors trying to import from flask.ext.login/flask_login. Note that Flask itself & MongDB import fine (the code runs w/ all Flask extensions commented out).

Both extensions (using 'from xxx.ext.yyy') were working fine until a couple of weeks ago (but I don't work on the app very often, mostly just alter templates); that version is still working on the real server, but I can't run it on the (built-in) development server. I suspect some version change broke the import setup.

Since I had been fiddling w/ this project for a long time, & the directories were getting very cluttered, I made a new venv & did fresh installs of all the pkgs.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it to post without insane formatting (sigh)

Comment: did you use pip to install the packages or apt-get?

Comment: if you used pip try instead: `sudo apt-get install python-wtforms` that might work...

Comment: I installed the pkgs using pip.

Comment: Just to be complete: exthook.py comes w/ one of the pkgs (Flask?) & tries to smooth over the transition from' flask.ext.yyyy' to 'flask_yyyy' by modifying module names.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install python-wtforms' didn't work.